# Проблемы с библиотекой (arduino)

Tags: c++, g++, arduino

Есть библиотека:
[DynamicCollection.h](https://pastebin.com/7QRL3vFy)
[DynamicCollection.cpp](https://pastebin.com/Yn9ctWzT)
При компиляции всё нормально.
Но, вот такой код:

```
#include <DynamicCollection.h>

DynamicCollection<int> DColl();

void setup()
{
  DColl.Add(1);
}

void loop() {}
```

Почему-то выдаёт ошибку:

```
sketch_aug06a:7: error: request for member 'Add' in 'DColl', which is of non-class type 'DynamicCollection<int>()'  

DColl.Add(1);
     ^
exit status 1
request for member 'Add' in 'DColl', which is of non-class type 'DynamicCollection<int>()'
```

Почему так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DColl` объявляет функцию без параметров, возвращающую `DynamicCollection<int>`, а вовсе не объект. Нужно убрать пустые круглые скобки:

```
DynamicCollection<int> DColl;
```

Подробности можно найти по фразе "[most vexing parse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)".